# How to transfer data from one Excel input sheet to Excel database sheet? (system design)

Tags: excel, database, vba

I have this [input sheet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw6v8.png) in which the data is inputed and from which I have to transfer some of the fields. This form should be completed every day and the date at the corner should be changed.

Also, I have these [Database sheet for produced in reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFBZt.png) and [Database sheet for the setups of the machines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz43e.png) and I am using the date as a key. 
However, I want to check first whether these dates are already in the Real production database in order to excluse duplicates before occuring. The logic is if there is already the same date, the user can choose whether to overwrite it or cease the process, and if there is no such date, to transfer the data on the next free row.
The code for two of the three DB is below. How to change and finetune (probably the second loop) to have it not overwriting the whole DB with the last input value. Design improvements of the datebases would be also appreciated.

```
Sub TransferData()

'Turning off all screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim PA As Worksheet
Dim LT As Worksheet
Dim SDB As Worksheet
Dim PlanB As Worksheet
'    Dim PlanM As Worksheet
'    Dim PlanC As Worksheet
'    Dim PlanN As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

'Setting names for the sheets that we will use at this macro
Set PA = Sheets("ProdActual DB")
Set LT = Sheets("LT Delays DB")
Set SDB = Sheets("Setup DB")
Set PlanB = Sheets("PlanB")  
Dim Answer As String
Dim MyNote As String

'Creating a message box where the user will select if he wants to proceed or not with the Data Transfer
MyNote = ("Do you want to proceed with data transfer?")
Answer = MsgBox(MyNote, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Data transfer")
If Answer = vbNo Then
    Range("E8").Select
    GoTo 12
Else

    'Checking if the user has entered a Date in the given field.
    'If not the code brings up a msgbox asking him to enter one, selects the date's cell and stops running
    If PlanB.Cells(4, 20) = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("You haven't entered a date. Please enter a date!")
        PlanB.Activate
        PlanB.Cells(4, 9).Select
        GoTo 12
    End If

    'We loop in the database searching each row
    For i = 7 To 700
        'Making the code to search only the rows that data exist
        PA.Activate
        If PA.Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
            GoTo 11
            i = 700

            'Searching if the current date and its data has already been transfered and if
            'it's the case, brings up a message box asking the user to choose if he wants to
            'overwrite the data
        ElseIf PlanB.Cells(4, 20) = PA.Cells(i, 2) Then

            Dim Msg, Style, Response, MyString 'Title, Help, Ctxt
            Msg = "Date" & "" & PA.Cells(4, 20) & " " & "exists already in the database. Are you sure you want to overwrite the existing data for this date?" ' Define message.
            Style = vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbExclamation ' Define buttons.

            Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style)
            If Response = vbYes Then         ' User chose Yes.
                MyString = "YES"             ' Perform some action.
                'Creating a loop to go through the different entries in the follow-up sheet

                For k = 11 To 25
                    'Check for blanks and if it's product
                    If PlanB.Cells(k, 2) <> "" And Left(PlanB.Cells(k, 2), 5) = "ROUND" Then

                        PA.Cells(i, 2) = PlanB.Cells(4, 20) 'transfer the date in the production actual DB
                        PA.Cells(i, 3) = PlanB.Cells(3, 20) 'transfer the line
                        PA.Cells(i, 4) = PlanB.Cells(2, 20) 'transfer the shift
                        PA.Cells(i, 5) = PlanB.Cells(k, 3) 'product code
                        PA.Cells(i, 7) = PlanB.Cells(k, 14) 'produced qty
                        PA.Cells(i, 8) = PlanB.Cells(k, 13) - PlanB.Cells(k, 12) 'duration of the run
                        PA.Cells(i, 9) = PA.Cells(i, 8) - PlanB.Cells(k, 9) 'total difference planned/actual

                        'If it is not product and it is not blank then it goes as a changeover/setup
                    ElseIf PlanB.Cells(k, 2) <> "" Then
                        SDB.Cells(i, 2) = PlanB.Cells(4, 20) 'transfer the date in the Setup DB
                        SDB.Cells(i, 3) = PlanB.Cells(3, 20) 'transfer the line
                        SDB.Cells(i, 4) = PlanB.Cells(2, 20) 'transfer the shift
                        SDB.Cells(i, 5) = PlanB.Cells(k, 2) 'transfer the description
                        SDB.Cells(i, 6) = PlanB.Cells(k, 9) 'standard duration

                    End If
                Next k

            ElseIf Response = vbNo Then      ' User chose No.
                MyString = "NO"              ' Perform some action.
                PlanB.Activate
                PlanB.Cells(4, 20).Select
                GoTo 12
            End If
        End If
    Next i
 11

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 12

End Sub
```

The

Comment: Use the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) to match your date with a range. If it matches it returns the row number of the match (so you can overwrite in that row) if it does not match it throws an error (in this case you need to insert a new row. • Note that Excel is not a database. You might want to switch to a real database where this kind of actions could easily be handled with an sql statement.

Comment: Then how could I handle the other case when the function returns an error since this will be the most frequent case? (believe, I would've switched if I could)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) to match your date with a range. If it matches it returns the row number of the match (so you can overwrite in that row) if it does not match it throws an error (in this case you need to insert a new row

Here is an example how to handle it:

```
Dim MatchedRow As Double
MatchedRow = 0 'initialize
On Error Resume Next 'disable error reporting
MatchedRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Lookup_Value, Lookup_array, 0)
On Error Goto 0 'enable error reporting

'if Match errored then MatchedRow will still be the initial value 0
If MatchedRow = 0 Then
    'Nothing matched add new row
Else
    'otherwise use MatchedRow to access the cells in that row to override your data for that date
    YourSheet.Cells(MatchedRow, "A").Value = "override row")
End If
```

- `Lookup_Value` is your date
- `Lookup_array` is the range you search for your date
- `YourSheet` needs to be replaced with a reference to your sheet.

For more info about error handling: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).